# C++: [VS2010]: warning C4396: 'stdext::hash_value' : the inline specifier cannot be used when a friend declaration

Tags: c++

I am converting my VS2005 C++ code to VS2010 code. Unfortunately in VS2010 it is giving compiler warning whereas in VS2005 it compiled smoothly. (FYI: I have set the warning to be treated as errors).

Pls have a look at the code snippet:

The error is at the line where the friend declaration is there.

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyKey
{
    friend size_t stdext::hash_value<MyKey>(const MyKey& key);  // compiler warning at this line (pls see below for the actual compiler warning)

    ubit32  m_uKey1;

};
template<> inline size_t stdext::hash_value<MyKey>(const MyKey& key)
{
    return key.m_uKey1;
}
```

Here is the compiler warning as shown below:

```
warning C4396: 'stdext::hash_value' : the inline specifier cannot be used when a friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template
```

Please help to resolve this error for me. Thanks.

Comment: What part of the warning do you not understand?

Comment: @CodyGray: *how to fix it?*

Comment: What happens if you remove inline from "template<> inline size_t stdext::hash_value<MyKey>(const MyKey& key)" ?

Comment: What is the declaration of the `stdext::has_value` primary template? Is it available *before* the `friend` declaration? Is the real `friend` declaration **exactly** as shown in the question? (i.e. there is not `inline` in the `friend` declaration, is there?)

Comment: I am still getting error if I remove the inline from the "template<> inline size_t stdext::hash_value<MyKey>(const MyKey& key)"

the original implementation of stdext::hash_value is in <xhash> file as below

template<class _Kty> inline
 size_t hash_value(const _Kty& _Keyval)
 { // hash _Keyval to size_t value one-to-one
 return ((size_t)_Keyval ^ _HASH_SEED);
 }

So please help me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the fix by adding the following two forward declaration statements before the class declaration for MyKey.

```
class MyKey;

template<> size_t stdext::hash_value<MyKey>(const MyKey& key);
```

Now the error/warning is gone. Am I doing it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your friend declaration doesn't have the `inline` specifier, this is obviously a bug in MSVC compiler. You can suppress the warning with a compiler option or a pragma:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4396)
```